# Could anyone help me with if statements and strings in C++?

Tags: c++

I am having a bit of trouble with if statements and strings/characters in c++. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "|Welcome to Castle Clashers!|" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;

    cout << "Would you like to start?" << endl;

    string input;

    cout << "A. Yes ";
    cout << "B. No " << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if(input == "a" || "A"){
        cout << "Yes" << endl;
    }else{
        if(input == 'b' || 'B'){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

At my if statement it checks if the string input is equal to yes, and if it is not it should go to the else statement. This is where the trouble began, once I ran my program in the console when I type anything besides "a" or "A" it still says yes. I've tried doing it with chars/characters but I get the same output. Could anyone assist me?

Comment: order of operations. `||` is evaluated FIRST, so you're not testing `input` against two values, you're testing `input` against the RESULT of the `||` test.

Comment: Ah, the perils of translating natural language into code. `if(input == "a" || "A")` does not mean "if input is a or A" but "if input is a, or A is something that is truthy". You need to be explicit; "if input is a or input is A".

Comment: input == "a" || input == "A"

Comment: See `toupper` and `tolower` so you will only have to make either uppercase or lowercase comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"A"` and `'B'` will always be true in typical implementation.

You should also compare `input` against them.

Also compareing `std::string` with `char` doesn't seem supported, so you should also use string literals for `b` and `B`.

```
Try this:

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "|Welcome to Castle Clashers!|" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;

    cout << "Would you like to start?" << endl;

    string input;

    cout << "A. Yes ";
    cout << "B. No " << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if(input == "a" || input == "A"){
        cout << "Yes" << endl;
    }else{
        if(input == "b" || input == "B"){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It should be `input == "a" || input == "A"`. You have to test each case individually. Right now your code is equivalent to `(input == "a") || "A"`, which evaluates to `true` because `"A"` decays to a non-zero pointer.

Answer (score 2):

C didn't have "real" boolean values - instead, anything that equals 0 is considered *false*, and anything different from that is considered *true*. While C++ introduced a `bool` type, it still maintains the old C behavior for compatibility reasons.

As Cornstalk said, your `(input == "a" || "A")` is the same as `((input == "a") || ("A"))`, and `"A" != 0`, so it always evaluates to `true` - that's why it'll always enter into that if block.  What you want is:

`if (input == "a" || input == "A")`

The same holds true to the next statement (comparing it to 'B'), but there's one extra problem in there: You're using single quotes ( ' ) instead of double quotes ( " ), which makes it a `char` instead of a `string`. To make both variables the same type, just use double quotes, and it'll end up like this:

`if(input == "b" || input == "B")`

Comment: `"A"` evaluating to `true` doesn't mean C++ doesn't have "real" booleans. `bool` is a proper type in C++.

Comment: @Simple you're absolutely correct, I've edited my answer to fix that. Thanks for pointing it out!